# Loop inside loop - Display ArrayList

Tags: java, loops, jsp, for-loop, arraylist

I'm trying to diaplay ArrayList in JSP. I have to ArrayLists I want to loop through and display the data in the same JSP table. This works fine, for the first Arralist (history), but when I get to the second it displays all the ArrayList in each row, instead of the current index from the loop:

```
<table id="test" class="table text">
<tr>
    <th>Result</th>
    <th>Deposit</th>
    <th>Bet</th>
    <th>Return +/-</th>
    <th>Current balance</th>
    <th>Date</th>
</tr>
<%


for (history his : history) {

%>
<tr class="listing">


            <td><%=his.getRes()%></td>
            <td><%=resultTwoDecimalsDeposit%></td>
            <td><%=his.getOdds()%></td>
            <td><%=his.getDate() %> </td>
            <td style="color:#00cc00;"> + <%=resultTwoDecimalsRet%> </td>
```

Everything is fine until here. Instead of showing the current index from the loop, it displays all the ArrayList in each tr

```
<%  for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {    
%>

<td><%=list1.get(i) %></td>

<% } %>

<%}}}%>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Did you put a `<tr>` before the `for`? Please [edit] your question and include a real [mcve], not just code parts.

Comment: I did not put any other <tr> then shown here in the example -> I have 2 <tr> in total.

Comment: If you have only one `<tr>` and one `</tr>` then that's one row of output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is because of the nested loop. For each `his`, the complete inner `for` loop is executing which you do not want. You want that for each `history` element, the corresponding value from `list1` is displayed.

Do it as follows:

```
<table id="test" class="table text">
    <tr>
        <th>Result</th>
        <th>Deposit</th>
        <th>Bet</th>
        <th>Return +/-</th>
        <th>Current balance</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
    <%for (int i=0; i<history.size() && i<list1.size(); i++) {%>
        <tr class="listing">
            <td><%=history.get(i).getRes()%></td>
            <td><%=resultTwoDecimalsDeposit%></td>
            <td><%=history.get(i).getOdds()%></td>
            <td><%=history.get(i).getDate() %> </td>
            <td style="color:#00cc00;"> + <%=resultTwoDecimalsRet%> </td>           
            <td><%=list1.get(i) %></td>
        </tr>
    <%}%>           
</table>
```